# Sorting and Adding to ArrayList

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtextarea

So here's my code, I am making a program that sorts text into object instances that are created automatically when the user starts typing in a JTextArea. In a StudentList class here, I have String firstname, lastname, dateofbirth and year. When the user starts typing a StudentList instance is created, then the first text before the user makes a space stores as firstname and the text after the space lastname, the user presses enter and the text after enter becomes Date of Birth in format (mm/dd/yyyy) and user presses enter again and the text after enter becomes year(in the form "Year num, i.e Year 10, Year 12...).
For example: Joseph\sNancy
             \n03/04/1999
             \nYear 11
firstname becomes: Joseph, lastname: Nancy. dateofbirth: 03/04/1999 year: Year 11 for the first Object instance created of Type StudentList.

Afterwards, after the first Object is created and year(the last instance variable) is stored, I'll like another instance of StudentList where the process repeats itself if text is entered after Year... Help
All the newly created StudentList gets added to ArrayList

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class InfoAdd implements KeyListener {
    private JTextArea textar;
    private JTextArea textarea;
    private JPanel panel;
    ArrayList <StudentList> stdlist;

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        InfoAdd inadd = new InfoAdd();
        inadd.go();

    }

    public void go() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("InfoAdd");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        panel = new JPanel();
        JPanel btpanel = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton("Click");
        textarea = new JTextArea(10, 15);
        textar = new JTextArea(10, 15);
        JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(textarea);
        JScrollPane scrollpan = new JScrollPane(textar);
        textarea.addKeyListener(this);
        textarea.setLineWrap(true);
        textar.setLineWrap(true);

        scrollpane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollpane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scrollpan.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollpan.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        panel.add(scrollpane);
        panel.add(scrollpan);
        btpanel.add(button);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.add(BorderLayout.WEST, panel);
        frame.add(BorderLayout.EAST, btpanel);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        String add = textarea.getText();
        String [] delimiter = add.split("\\s+");
        String [] enter = add.split("[\\r\\n]+");
        stdlist = new ArrayList<StudentList>();
        for(int i=0;i<add.length();i++) {
            StudentList sdt = new StudentList();
            if(delimiter.length==2) {
                sdt.SetFirstName(delimiter[i]);

            }

            stdlist.add(sdt);
            textar.setEditable(false);
            textar.setText("Firstname: "+sdt.getFirstName()+"\nLastName: "+sdt.getLastName()+"\nYear: ");
        }
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }



    class StudentList {
        private String firstname;
        private String lastname;
        private String year;
        private String dateofbirth;


        public void SetFirstName(String y) {
            y = firstname;
        }
        public void setLastName(String c) {
            c = lastname;
        }
        public void setYear(String t) {
            t = year;
        }
        public void setDateofBirth(String u) {
            u = dateofbirth;
        }
        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstname;
        }
        public String getLastName() {
            return lastname;
        }
        public String getYear() {
            return year;
        }
        public String getDateofBirth(){
            return dateofbirth;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: One thing worth fixing first is the assignment in your ```StudentList``` setters, they're the wrong way around so you're attempting to assign the member value to the parameter rather than the parameter value to the member field. e.g. it should be ```public void setFirstName(String y) { firstname = y; }``` (On a side note ```y``` is not a great name).

Comment: When you want to listen to text changes in text components, use a `DocumentListener` instead of a `KeyListener`. Like: `textArea.getDocument().addDocumentListener()`

Answer (score 0):

as d.j.brown mention your setter creation is wrong and i change some code line in `InfoAdd` class.(netbeans, intellij idea, eclipse if you are using one of these IDE. this IDE give facility to generate getters and setters. use it then you don't get trouble)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
public class InfoAdd implements KeyListener {
    private JTextArea textar;
    private JTextArea textarea;
    private JPanel panel;
    ArrayList<StudentList> stdlist;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InfoAdd inadd = new InfoAdd();
        inadd.go();
    }
    public void go() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("InfoAdd");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        panel = new JPanel();
        JPanel btpanel = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton("Click");
        textarea = new JTextArea(10, 15);
        textar = new JTextArea(10, 15);
        JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(textarea);
        JScrollPane scrollpan = new JScrollPane(textar);
        textarea.addKeyListener(this);
        textarea.setLineWrap(true);
        textar.setLineWrap(true);
        scrollpane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollpane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scrollpan.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollpan.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        panel.add(scrollpane);
        panel.add(scrollpan);
        btpanel.add(button);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.add(BorderLayout.WEST, panel);
        frame.add(BorderLayout.EAST, btpanel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        String add = textarea.getText();
        String[] delimiter = add.split("\\s+");
        String[] enter = add.split("[\\r\\n]+");
        stdlist = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= add.length(); i++) {
        StudentList studentList = new StudentList();
        System.out.println(delimiter.length);
        switch (enter.length) {
                case 1:
                    setName(delimiter, studentList);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    setName(delimiter, studentList);
                    studentList.setDateofbirth(enter[1]);
                    break;
                default:
                    setName(delimiter, studentList);
                    studentList.setDateofbirth(enter[1]);
                    studentList.setYear(enter[2]);
                    break;
            }
            stdlist.add(studentList);
            textar.setEditable(false);
            textar.setText("Firstname: " + studentList.getFirstname() + "\nLastName: " + studentList.getLastname()+" \nDateOfBirth: "+studentList.getDateofbirth() + "\nYear: " + studentList.getYear());
        }
    }
    private void setName(String[] delimiter, StudentList studentList) {
        if (delimiter.length == 1) {
            studentList.setFirstname(delimiter[0]);
        } else if (delimiter.length == 2) {
            studentList.setFirstname(delimiter[0]);
            studentList.setLastname(delimiter[1]);
        }
    }
    class StudentList {
        private String firstname;
        private String lastname;
        private String year;
        private String dateofbirth;
        public String getFirstname() {
            return firstname;
        }
        public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
            this.firstname = firstname;
        }
        public String getLastname() {
            return lastname;
        }
        public void setLastname(String lastname) {
            this.lastname = lastname;
        }
        public String getYear() {
            return year;
        }
        public void setYear(String year) {
            this.year = year;
        }
        public String getDateofbirth() {
            return dateofbirth;
        }
        public void setDateofbirth(String dateofbirth) {
            this.dateofbirth = dateofbirth;
        }
    }
}
```